# Calculating difference between unique pairs of elements - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix containing two columns - position `A(:,1)` and index `A(:,2)`:

```
A=
10   1
15   1
5    2
10   2
18   2
20   2
24   3
30   3
35   3
```

I need to be able to calculate the distance (between position values) between each element and all others within each index block - omitting non-unique, redundant pairs. The desired output for the above example would be:

**Index 1**

```
5 (15-10)
```

Explanation: Distance between 10 and 15. Distance between 15 and 10 is not taken as this is not unique and has already been calculated.

**Index 2**

```
5 (10-5)
13 (18-5)
15 (20-5)
8 (18-10)
10 (20-10)
2 (20-18)
```

**Index 3**

```
6 (30-24)
11 (35-24)
5 (35-30)
```

These results can just be placed into a single matrix:

```
diff=
5
5
13
15
8
10
2
6
11
5
```

Is there a concise way to do this without a convoluted mixture of for loops and if statements?

Comment: The result you are showing is not the desired reuslt, right? It contains non-unique elements.

Comment: Does column 2 always contain numbers of the form 1, 2, 3,...?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes - it will always take the form 1:1:16.

Comment: @TheodorBecker I can't see any non-unique pairs. The uniqueness resets within each index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in one line using [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with an anonymous function:

```
result = accumarray(A(:,2), A(:,1), [], @(x) {unique(pdist(x))});
```

In your example, this gives

```
result{1} =
     5
result{2} =
     2     5     8    10    13    15
result{3} =
     5     6    11
```

This uses the function [`pdist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) from the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have it, you can do

```
result = accumarray(A(:,2), A(:,1), [], @(x) {unique(nonzeros(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x,x.'))))});
```